# pass multiple parameters to form from html table in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-tables2

I am newbie with Django and I get stucked trying to pass the value from a html table rendered with django-tables2 to a form.

view.py

```
def configView(request):
    form = ConfigForm(request.POST or none)

    if form.is_valid():
       save_it = form.save(commit=False)
       save_it.save()
       Messages.success(request, 'Configuracion Actualizada')
       return HttpResponseRedirect('/monitor/')

    return render_to_response("config.html",
                              locals(),
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This is my forms.py

```
class ConfigForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = Config

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ConfigForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['id_proveedor'].initial = kwargs.pop('id_proveedor',None)
```

But I don't know how to retrieve and pass the value to theform.
I need pass the values from the cells 0, 2 and 6.

Any advice or snippet will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll need to add your template, but you can't just submit a table into a form. You'll have to create hidden inputs and populate them with the values in the cells.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

class ConfigForm(forms.Form):

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    your_variable_to_pass = kwargs.pop("your_variable_to_pass")
    super(ConfigForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.fields['id_proveedor']= forms.FieldClass(attribute=your_variable_to_pass)

id_proveedor = FieldClass()
```

where, 'FieldClass' is whatever field you choose (i.e. ChoiceField, CharField) and 
attribute is the attribute to pass (your variable), i.e. 'choices', 'initial' etc.
thus, it may look like this:
     self.fields['id_proveedor']= forms.ChoiceField(choices=your_variable_to_pass)

id_proveedor = ChoiceField()

## Notice indentation - you assign value of the attribute to pass in the constructor!; in case of ChoiceField choices is a list of tuples, i.e. (('1', 'First',), ('2', 'Second',)); I use Forms instead of ModelForm as super or base class in this example

Then, in the views: f = ConfigFrom(request.POST, your_variable_to_pass=your_variable_to_pass)

## notice  your_variable_to_pass=your_variable_to_pass otherwise it'll generate a key error

I hope, it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply Leo, but where I am confused is how can get the values from the html table and pass it to the form. I want to pass the values from the cells 0 and 3 from the selected row